# returning function calling another returning function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, angular-services, angular-promise

Im trying to call a returning function inside another returning function but I'm getting myfunctionName is undefined.. here is the code

```
function(){
... 
....
return{
      myfunction1: function(param1,param2){
        var doSomethingHere;
      },
      myfunction2: function(){
          ....
          var param1,param2
          .... 
          //I get an error here
          myfunction1(param1,param2).then(function(return){
             console.log(return);
          });
      }
    }
}
```

so how can I call myfunction1 inside myFunction2 whiouth getting the error "is not defined"

Comment: Create an object to return as a variable, then use a reference to the function like `obj.myfunction1`.

Comment: `this.myfunction1()` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The revealing module pattern can help with this

```
function(){
    var myfunction1 = function(param1,param2){
        var doSomethingHere;
    }

    var myfunction2 = function(){
          ....
          var param1,param2
          .... 
          //I get an error here
          myfunction1(param1,param2).then(function(return){
             console.log(return);
          });
    }

    return{
      myfunction1: myfunction1,
      myfunction2: myfunction2
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked the downside of if is that I have to write the name of the functions twice plus the definition of the function itself Im not sure if there is another way. but anyway it worked.

Comment: @JAT2007 the module you return doesn't _have_ to have the same name as the function. There are other ways, but this is a popular pattern.